# Disable Accordion Action with Jquery Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a combination of JqueryUI's Accordion and Tabs, but I can't figure out how to get the accordion to properly function since with the layout, the tabs are inside the "header" area and so every time I click on the tabs, it is toggling the accordion as well.

I tried to get more granular with the header like this:

```
$( ".accordion" )
.accordion({
    header: "> div >  ul > li:first-child",
    collapsible: true
})
```

It screws up the styling. Here is the live example:
http://jsfiddle.net/a30kfn01/2/

Answer (score 0):

Ended up finding this would work, of course you can also add an `if` statement to get even more granular:

```
$('.accordion li').click(function(e) {      
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;      
}); 

$( ".accordion" )
.accordion({
    header: "> div > ul",
    collapsible: true
})
```